# Python with sqlite3 - inputs random value after few minutes run

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm working with my new project. Python script is **scraping** webstore then it saves all the available items into the sqlite3 database. Ofcourse it works in while True loop. It has 3 columns: itemid, price, checker. Checker is used to check if item is already in db. If it is I'm sending UPDATE query which changes the checker value to X. If it is not available any more that field stays empty. After few loops it checks if every item has 'X' at the checker field. If not it deletes rows without it.

It works perfect for a few minutes. Items are getting added to the db, some are getting delteted etc.
But I don't know what is happening after few minutes when some new items are added to the shop. 'price' column gets set to 1.0 (for EVERY item) and then it goes for wrong loop with "changed item price" and "added new item". Next loops don't change that 1.0 value (I'm using DB Browser for SQLite to check script work)

I'm sure thats not the problem with **scraped** content because if I print it before adding to the db it shows everything every time correctly. Also everytime webhook is beeing sent with correct informations.

Here is part of my code which probably causes the issues:

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS webstore (itemid text, price real, checker text)")
... 
scraping things...
...
                        c.execute(("SELECT * from webstore WHERE itemid='{0}' AND price='{1}'").format(itemID, itemPrice))
                        time.sleep(0.05)
                        if c.fetchone() == None:
                            c.execute(("INSERT INTO webstore VALUES('{0}','{1}','X')").format(itemID, itemPrice)) #case for new item
                            sendHook(itemID, itemPrice, itemLink, itemPhoto, "Added new item") #sends discord webhook - shows always correct informations
                            print(f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Added new item: "+itemID)         
                            time.sleep(0.5)

                        c.execute(("SELECT * from webstore WHERE itemid='{0}' AND price != '{1}'").format(itemID, itemPrice)) #case for item with changed price
                        time.sleep(0.05)
                        if c.fetchone() != None:
                            c.execute(("UPDATE webstore SET price='{0}' AND checker='X'").format(itemPrice))
                            print(f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Changed price of "+itemID)
                            sendHook(itemID, itemPrice, itemLink, itemPhoto, "Price changed") #sends discord webhook - shows always correct informations
                            time.sleep(0.5)
                            
                        c.execute(("SELECT * from webstore WHERE itemid='{0}' AND price='{1}'").format(itemID, itemPrice)) #case for item that is alredy in db
                        time.sleep(0.05)
                        if c.fetchone() != None:
                            c.execute(("UPDATE webstore SET checker='X' WHERE itemid='{0}'").format(itemID))
                            print (f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] No changes")
                            time.sleep(0.1)
                    conn.commit() 
....
   if loopCounter == 5:
        c.execute("DELETE FROM webstore WHERE checker=' '") #after every 5 loops it deletes items without 'X' in checker field
        c.execute("UPDATE webstore SET checker=' '")
        conn.commit()
        loopCounter = 0
```

Do you know where the issue can be?

Comment: Have you tried debugging with some `print()` statements?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, I was trying to print every variable before executing db query and everything was fine

Comment: You should not be using `format` to create your SQL strings.  If any of those string contain a single quote, you're screwed.  Let sqlite3 do the substitution, it knows the quoting rules.  `c.execute("SELECT * FROM webstore WHERE itemid=? AND price=?;", (itemID, itemPrice))`.  And there is no point in sleeping after an execute.  Sqlite3 is synchronous.  It won't return until it's done.

Comment: You can do this with one fetch.  Just fetch the row where itemid matches.  Then, there are three cases: it doesn't exist, it exists with the same price, it exists with a new price.